# Binary search and insert

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insert, binary-search

I've stumbled on a problem with my coding and I can't see where it goes wrong.

I am working on a program where I need to use binary search, followed by an insert. After executing all items should be sorted, but this is not the case at the moment.

My code is as follows:

```
//Array is 103, 102, 101, 105, 106

public int insert(int itemid) {
     int[] newItems = new int[items.length + 1];

itemPos = Arrays.binarySearch(items, 0, itemsLength, itemid);    

    if (itemPos < 0) {
        itemPos = -itemPos - 1;
    }

    System.arraycopy(items, 0, newItems, 0, items.length);
    items = newItems;

    items[itemPos+1] = itemid; 

    itemsLength++;

    System.out.println("item position: " + itemPos);
    System.out.println("item: " + Arrays.toString(items));
    System.out.println("itemslength: " + itemsLength);

    return itemPos;
}
```

The output when I run my code is now:

```
 item position: 0
 item: [103, 102]
 itemslength: 1
 item position: 0
 item: [103, 101, 0]
 itemslength: 2
 item position: 2
 item: [103, 101, 0, 105]
 itemslength: 3
 item position: 3
 item: [103, 101, 0, 105, 106]
```

The only problem I’ve got now is that the array is not sorted (and that it gives a zero when it should be a 102, but maybe it is the same sorting problem). I would appreciate it very much if someone would point me in the right direction.

Greetings,

Alfred

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore how binary searching works. You will find that in order for it work, the items being searched *must* be sorted. That is what is misguiding the insert position.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `items` starts out sorted.

As you are inserting into the middle of the array, you will need 2 `arrayCopy`s to copy the items on either side of the new position.

`itemPos` is the location where the new item should be inserted, don't add `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a beginner in coding. Honestly, unable to understand your code. But I have written some insertion code using binary search. It searches for an index before inserting and inserts the elements in a sorted array. Hope this helps you!!

```
public class Insertion {
private int[] a;
int n;
int c;

public Insertion()
{
    a = new int[10];
    n=0;
}

int find(int key)
{
    int lowerbound = 0;
    int upperbound = n-1;

    while(true)
    {
        c = (lowerbound + upperbound)/2;
        if(n==0)
            return 0;
        if(lowerbound>=upperbound)
        {
            if(a[c]<key)
                return c++;
            else
                return c;
        }
        if(a[c]>key && a[c-1]<key)
            return c;
        else if (a[c]<key && a[c+1]>key)
            return c++;
        else
        {
            if(a[c]>key)
                upperbound = c-1;
            else
                lowerbound = c+1;
        }
    }
}

void insert(int key)
{
   find(key);
   for(int k=n;k>c;k--)
   {
       a[k]=a[k-1];
   }
   a[c]=key;
   n++;
}
void display()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Insertion i=new Insertion();
    i.insert(56);
    i.insert(1);
    i.insert(78);
    i.insert(3);
    i.insert(4);
    i.insert(200);
    i.insert(6);
    i.insert(7);
    i.insert(1000);
    i.insert(9);
    i.display();
}
```

}

Please provide me feedback for any mistakes, discrepancies etc. Happy coding!!